# MultiSelect List View not detecting unchecked fields on android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a multiSelec listView fills with days. I´m getting the items selected, my problem is when I click in one list field in order to unselect it. An example:
I check the position 1,2,3,4,5 on the list and after that I uncheck the 4,5 position , so finally I have 3 fields checked.
With my code I get 5 values checked instead 3 . 
¿Can anyone help me?
What I'm doing wrong?

```
private void gettingDaysChecked(){

        boolean isSomethingChecked = false;

        SparseBooleanArray checked = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();
        Log.d(Constants.TAG,"cheched size is "+checked.size() );


       if (checked.size()>0)
          isSomethingChecked=true;


        if (isSomethingChecked) {
            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
                int positionItem = checked.keyAt(i);
                Log.d(Constants.TAG, "in position" + positionItem);
                localList.add(positionItem);

            }
            app.setDaysCheckedFilterPeriod(localList);

        }else if(!isSomethingChecked){
            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"nothing checked ");

        }

    }
```

Comment: you are using Custom ListView with Checkbox or wat?

Comment: Are you calling `gettingDaysChecked()` after you check 5 items and then uncheck 2 of them? Or you calling this function periodically?

Can you provide more code?

Comment: Thanks, I´m using  simple_list_item_multiple_choice. The calling to gettingDaysChecked() is after the user clicks on a button "DONE"

Comment: Add the `setOnItemclickListner()` code for `ListView` so that we can help u.

Comment: here is  http://pastebin.com/zT420kk2

Comment: instead of `SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = mListView.getCheckedItemPositions();` try `SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = parent.getCheckedItemPositions();`

Comment: Thanks I did it but it´doesnt work , really strange is that on gettingDaysChecked() , following the first example  if I do mListView.getCheckedItemCount() I get 3 fields checked  O_o

Comment: check [This](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-multiple-selection-listview/) and [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-delete-multiple-selected-items-listview-tutorial/) example it may help you